# ActionLink and Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a website where there are products and you can leave reviews on products. I have a link on the product page that says "Leave a review"

In my code it looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Leave a Review", "AddReview", "Product", new { id = Model.ProductId }, null)
```

When I run my application the link works fine, but when I submit a review it crashes and says:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Product(System.String, Int32)' in
>   'MyProject.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

This error only occurs if I have `new { id = Model.ProductId }` in my ActionLink.

This may seem like the ProductId is null, but that isn't possible. To load up the product page in the first place a ProductId is needed, plus I use a RenderAction that displays reviews about that product on the page using that same id:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Reviews", "product", new { id = Model.ProductId});}
```

So basically, why am I getting this error?
Does it have something to do with there being a GET and POST AddReview method? I don't think it should considering the link would pull the GET and when I submit the form it should be a POST. How do I get the productId into the form?

**EDIT**
To answer some questions:

My form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddReview", "Product"))
{
    <p>Title @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Title)</p>
    <p>Rating: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Rating)</p>
    <p>Body: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Body)</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home");
}
```

My generated  tag looks like this:

```
<a href="/Product/AddReview?ProductId=9">Leave a Review</a>
```

**EDIT**

After having fixed the link issue I realized that the reason I was still getting an error was because of a RedirectToAction call was broken in my controller. What a stupid mistake!

Comment: What does the code to create the form look like?

Comment: How does the `<a>` tag look in the generated HTML when you browse the source?

Comment: I have added both of these to my original post.

Comment: Can we see the actions in your ProductController that you are using? It feels to me as if you think you are passing one parameter, but you're instead sending another. I would like to see what's going on in your controller.

Comment: I fixed it. Shyju's answer fixed my link and then I realized that something else was broken in my controller.

Comment: Why do you need a link to add a new review on the same page as your add new review form?

Comment: They're not on the same page. My link is on the product page. Reviews are displayed on the same age with the product but to WRITE a review you click the link and it takes you to a separate page to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Leave a Review", "AddReview", "Product", new { @id = Model.ProductId }, null)
```

This should generate a link like below if you have a valid valie in your ProductId property for this model

```
<a href="/Product/AddReview/9">Leave a Review</a>
```

Make sure you have the `ProductId` Property value loaded properly.

you may use `@` symbol as a prefix to parameters which has the same name as of HTML attribues. See i used `@id` instead of `id`

Comment: This generates the proper link. I still get the error and I suspect that's because I'm not loading the value into my form properly...

Comment: And yet the review still posts.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="/Product/AddReview?ProductId=9">Leave a Review</a>
```

is not good. You should get:

```
<a href="/Product/AddReview/9">Leave a Review</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="/Product/AddReview?id=9">Leave a Review</a>
```

because your controller action expects a non-nullable int parameter called `id`. The reason you are getting this wrong url might be because you have messed up with your routes.

Comment: I haven't touched my routes though. It's the default {controller}/{action}/{id} setup.

Comment: Maybe it's your form then. Have you tried including the route parameter: `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddReview", "Product", new { id = Model.ProductId }, FormMethod.Post))`?

Comment: So, I get the error but the reviews still post. That's silly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not setting the ProductId in the form. You either need to set the form action to include the id in the route: `@Html.BeginForm("AddReview","Product", new {Id = Model.ProductId})` or include a hidden input for the productId, e.g. `@Html.Hidden("id",Model.ProductId")`

Comment: How do I pass the ID into the form then?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, it is better to pass the ID in the form action or in a hidden? Pros and cons...

Comment: @Romias I think the form value wins if they are different.